# Is there a Google cloud Real user monitoring (RUM) solution?

Tags: azure, google-cloud-platform, synthetic, rum

Do we have any Azure and GCP cloud-native solutions for Real user monitoring (RUM) and Synthetics?
I have tested AWS CW for RUM and synthetics but need a similar solution in Azure and GCP.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, currently Google Cloud has no RUM solution. You'll have to rely on 3rd party services such as mPulse, Datadog or [PageVitals](https://pagevitals.com).

If for some reason you prefer a 3rd party tool that runs exclusively on Google Cloud, PageVitals is an option. Full disclosure: I work for this company.

Answer (score -1):

Google Cloud do have a [Cloud Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring#section-6) solution, you can see the list of Google Cloud services that have similar offering in Amazon Web Services (AWS) and Microsoft Azure from this documentation on [Compare AWS and Azure services to Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/aws-azure-gcp-service-comparison).

Comment: Aware about Cloud monitoring. But i could not find RUM in GCP.. Do we have Real User Monitoring solution in GCP?